# Place footer at the bottom of a web page in React app

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, footer

I am new in reactjs. I tried many solutions, but can't fix my footer to show at the bottom of the web page after displaying the web content. In this scenario, if web page has less content, footer is sitting right after end of the web content, instead of sitting at bottom. Moreover, I also tried with position:fixed, which practically shows the footer always stick at the bottom of the page, and sometime, some of the contents got hide back of the footer if web page is long.
Can you guys please help me to get rid of this issue.

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header></Header>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home></Home>}></Route>
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home></Home>}></Route>
        <Route path="/blogs" element={<Blogs></Blogs>}></Route>
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login></Login>}></Route>
        <Route path="/register" element={<Register></Register>}></Route>
        <Route path="*" element={<NotFound></NotFound>}></Route>
       
      <Footer></Footer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```css
.footer {
    background-color: #758283;
    color: white;
    position: relative;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 20px 40px;

    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Please insert a link to your source code.

Comment: https://github.com/ProgrammingHeroWC4/warehouse-management-client-side-dilshadara

Comment: Your link has an issue. ( error 404)

Comment: If you think about modules or components, in the end everything follows the normal flow of a HTML document anyways. I have never used a framework front-end, your own HTML/CSS/JS is more than enough for 99% of websites, that includes SPA's.

Answer (score 2):

It is discouraged to use uppercase letters in class names. I am going to use `app` instead of `App`.

1. Add `main` class to the main content
2. Make `app` a flex container:

```css
.app {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  min-height: 100vh; /* or the minimum height of your content */
}

.main {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

That will make the main content grow to fill the rest of the screen if there is not enough content, pushing the footer to the bottom.

Comment: {min-height: 100vh} did the trick for me!